# Does Android store log files for file modifications?

Tags: android

I'm interested in the question whether or not Android stores log files logging data such as "file X was modified on XXXX by app XYZ" or similar.
Does something like this exist?

Comment: Android does not log such information at all. If you want it you have to monitor the file-system yourself, e.g. using the Java API https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver or directly via adb using the standard Linux programs like `inotify-tools`.